# How to sent an email background with Swift code (macOS)

Tags: swift, cocoa, background, sendmail, send

this code works fine but it pops a window, then have to click send. Can I send it in the background without pops a window?
Thank everybody!

```
import Cocoa

class SendEmail: NSObject {
    static func send() {
        let service = NSSharingService(named: NSSharingServiceNameComposeEmail)!
        service.recipients = ["abc@dom.com"]
        service.subject = "Vea software"
        
        service.performWithItems(["This is an email for auto testing through code."])
    }
}
SendEmail.send()
```

Comment: I sure hope not -- that seems like it would be a terrible security issue.

Comment: Nope.  You cannot automatically send a message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that, this would be quite not secure if a dev could sent any email from user's address without even letting him know

In background you can send a http request to your server which will send an email, but it will send it from your developer/organization/etc address, not from user's one ofc.